# Org-mode cycling headline excerpts?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to view my org file like a blog, where top-level headlines display a short summary of their contents, when folded (say the first 5 lines). Is there a way to do this with cycling? Or through Agenda views perhaps?

Thanks!

Comment: [org-agenda-entry-text-mode](http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html#Agenda-commands) (E key binding) will show the first few lines in every entry in agenda view.